# bus manager fails because service is already taken, why

Tags: network-manager

I am running ubuntu 22.04. after the boot I look at the journalctl using this command:`

```
journalctl -xb | grep "error"`
```

I have 5 lines returned like this:

```
Mar 10 15:51:43 ubuntu NetworkManager[974]: <error> [1710107503.4015] bus-manager: fatal failure to acquire D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (3). Service already taken
```

I do not have the wired Ethernet plugged in and think I have disabled it.
I am using wireless which works fine.

Any ideas about what might be causing this?

Comment: That error states that Network Manager is already taken as a service name.  That's not anything to do with Ethernet.  Chances are Network Manager is already your wifi handler, and this is just a notice that you can somewhat safely ignore